# Sails.js controller not inserting into Mongo database

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I've been all over SO and Sailsjs.org trying to figure out what's going wrong, and to no avail. Just trying to learn the basics of SailsJS. I have a UserController, whose `create()` method gets called when a `POST` request is sent to `/user`.

```
create: function (req, res) {
    var params = req.params.all();

    User.create({
        name: params.FirstName + ' ' + params.LastName,
        email: params.Email,
        password: params.Password,
        jobTitle: params.JobTitle
    }).exec(function createCB(err,created)
    {
        created.save(function(err)
        {
            // No error . . . still nothing in db
        });
        return res.json({name: created.name, jobTitle: created.jobTitle, email: created.email, password: created.password});
    });
}
```

No errors here. All the request params are coming in fine and going back to the client without trouble. But nothing is actually being written to the database.

In development.js:

```
connections: {
    mongo: {
        adapter: 'sails-mongo',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        // user: 'username',
        // password: 'password',
        database: 'sails_test'
    }
},

models: {
    connection: 'mongo'
}
```

I've tried this with the above both there in development.js, as well as separately in connections.js and models.js, respectively. No difference.

In User.js:

```
attributes: {

    FirstName : { type: 'string' },

    LastName : { type: 'string' },

    Email : { type: 'string' },

    Password : { type: 'string' },

    JobTitle : { type: 'string' }
}
```

My front end request:

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/user',
        data: {
            FirstName: 'Yo', 
            LastName: 'Momma',
            Email: 'yourmom@yourdadshouse.com',
            Password: 'YouWish123',
            JobTitle: 'Home Maker Extraordinaire'
        },
        success: function (sailsResponse) 
        {
            $('#result').html(sailsResponse).fadeIn();
        },
        error: function()
        {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
```

Again, none of this is producing an explicit error. There is just nothing being inserted into the database. Or if there is, I don't know how to find it. I've confirmed the existence of this db in the mongo shell, thusly:

```
show dbs
```

My db, `sails_test` shows up in the list. And I've confirmed that there isn't anything in it like so:

```
db.sails_test.find()
```

I would very much appreciate some guidance here :)

**Update:**

Turns out the data is being written just fine. I'm just unable to query the database from the command line. I confirmed this by first creating a sample user, and then using Waterline's `findOne()` method:

```
User.findOne({FirstName: params.FirstName}).exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(400);
    } else if (user) {
        return res.json({firstName: user.FirstName, lastName: user.LastName, jobTitle: user.JobTitle, email: user.Email, password: user.Password});
    } else {
        return res.send('no users match those criteria');
    }
});
```

The above works as expected. So my problem now is simply that I cannot interact with the database from the command line. `db.<collectionName>.find({})` produces nothing.

Comment: have you confirmed that ```req.params.all()``` contains the correct params? I ask because of https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2524

Comment: Yep, I can pass the params between client and server without a problem.

Comment: Have you seen any difference if you use sails-disk or sails-memory adapters. Just curious. The ```created.save()``` method in your controller is unnecessary, but should not be your problem.

Comment: Well, I was messing around with setting up the sails-disk adapter instead of mongo, and at some point a configuration I made for `localDiskDb` caused a record to be inserted into `db.test`, but only the one record. Also, at some point `db.sails` was created as well, but has no data. I wasn't paying close enough attention to know how that actually occurred.

Comment: Updated my question. The data is there after all, I just can't query the database from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply a failure to understand the MongoDb docs. I read `db.collection.find({})` as `DatabaseName.CollectionName.find({})`, when you literally need to use `db`. So if my database is Test, and my collection is Users, the query is `use Test`, and then `db.Users.find({})`.

Also of note, [3T Mongo Chef](http://3t.io/mongochef/) is a pretty rockin' GUI (graphical user interface) for nosql databases, and it's free for non-commercial use.